# Order Eloquent query by parent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel I have a situation like the one in the diagram below. I'd like to get all of a User's Orders, but sort the results by the `date` of the Event.

I have tried:

```
    $orders = auth()->user()->orders()->with(['tickets', 'event' => function($query) {
          $query->orderBy('date', 'desc');
    }])->get();
```

But the order seems completely random, and not in any way related to the date of the Event.

It feels like this must be possible, though?

[image]

Comment: date saved as int ?

Comment: Try this `auth()->user()->orders()->with('tickets')->orderBy('tickets.date', 'desc')->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinink wrote a great [article](https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel)  about this kind of query

Your solution will order the **loaded** event(s) by date but you need to order **by** event date. So here what I suggest.

```
$orders = auth()->user()->orders()->orderByDesc(
    Event::select('date')->whereColumn('orders.event_id', 'events.id')
)->with(['tickets', 'event'])->get();
```

Comment: `latest()` has nothing to do with the date of the event, though. It merely orders the `created_at` column, which is simply when the data when entered into the database. It should either be `->orderBy('date', 'desc')` or `->latest('date')` (both of which are identical under the hood).

Comment: @ChuckLeButt You're right. You don't need the last two lines in fact. I did answer a bit too fast as I'm cooking ^_^

Comment: Yep, you're right. Those two lines were superfluous now that I think about it :) I will check out that article. Thanks.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt, in the article linked earlier, it says: sorting using sub query is slower than sorting using join by 200 times for this relation, I recommend sorting using join

Comment: @OMR Yes, I just saw that myself. It's unlikely to ever cause a problem, but it given the difference in timing it's still probably worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to get the orders with the events associated with ordered, you can do so like this:

```
Order::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with(['event' => function($query) {
   $query->latest('date');
}]);
```

(The latest method can receive the column name you wish to order by.)

Other Solution could be creating in the model, a relation scoped like:

```
public function orderedEvents()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Event::class)->latest('date');
}
```

Comment: These do not order the results correctly.

Comment: It worked for me, now it depends on what exactly you pretend to order

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$orders = auth()->user()->with(['orders.events' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('date', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

BTW, desc ordering of date looks wired. I think it's a better idea to use latest() instead of orderBy

Actually, the way you tried and I suggested, also complex and we fetched the current user unnecessarily. This looks better:

```
Order::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with(['event' => function($query) {
   $query->latest();
}]);
```

Comment: `latest()` has nothing to do with the date of the event, though. It merely orders the `created_at` column, which is simply when the data when entered into the database.

Comment: I didn't check the column name.